# Assign variable and redirect in bash

Tags: bash, curl

I'm doing ad-hoc profiling on a web service that seems to maintain some state and get slower and slower until eventually things start timing out. I have a simple script that will expose this behavior:

```
while true
do
    RESPONSE_CODE=$( curl --config curl.config )

    if [ "$RESPONSE_CODE" -eq "200" ]; then
        echo SUCCESS
    else
        echo FAILURE
    fi
done
```

Along with some headers, cookies, post data, url, etc. `curl.config` in particular has the lines:

```
silent
output = /dev/null
write-out = "%{http_code}"
```

So the only output from curl should be the HTTP status code.

This works fine. What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
{ time -p RESPONSE_CODE=$(curl --config curl.config) ; } 2>&1 | awk '/real/{print $2;}'
```

to get a running printout of how long these queries actually take, while still saving curl's output for use in my test. But that doesn't work.

How can I capture the http status from `curl` AND grab the output of `time` so I can process both?

Answer (score 1):

As written:

```
RESPONSE_CODE = $( curl --config curl.config )
```

you have spaces around the assignment which simply does not work in shell (it tries to execute a command `RESPONSE_CODE` with `=` as the first argument, etc.  You need:

```
RESPONSE_CODE=$( curl --config curl.config )
```

---

The `time` built-in is hard to redirect.  Since you need both HTTP status and real time, you will have to do something to capture both values.  One possibility is:

```
set -- $( (time -p -- curl --config curl.config ) 2>&1 |
         awk '/real/{print $2} /^[0-9]+$/{print}')
```

which will set $1 and $2.  Another is array assignment:

```
data=( $( (time -p -- curl --config curl.config ) 2>&1 |
         awk '/real/{print $2} /^[0-9]+$/{print}') )
```

The HTTP response code should appear before the time.

(Tested using `sh -c 'echo 200; sleep 1'` in lieu of `curl --config curl.config`.)

Comment: You're right about the variable assignment - it was correct in the script, and I flubbed it while redacting the script to post here. Question updated.

Comment: That did the trick, aside from `time` on OS X lacking the `--` option. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting note on portability.  The absence of support for the `--` option in the Mac OS X (BSD?) `time` command is arguably a bug (it contravenes the POSIX [Utility Syntax Guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) and specifically Guideline 10).

Answer (score 1):

This should work if Curl's response is only a single line:

```
#!/bin/bash
RESPONSE_CODE=''
TIME=''
while read -r TYPE DATA; do
    case "$TYPE" in
    curl)
        RESPONSE_CODE=$DATA
        ;;
    real)
        TIME=$DATA
        ;;
    esac
done < <(exec 2>&1; time -p R=$(curl --config curl.config); echo "curl $R")
```

Or use an associative array:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A RESPONSE
while read -r TYPE DATA; do
    RESPONSE[$TYPE]=$DATA
done < <(exec 2>&1; time -p R=$(curl ...); echo "code $R") 
echo "${RESPONSE[code] ${RESPONSE[real]}"
```